# .after() not working as intended

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm building a chrome extension and I have a block of code which goes like:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
return $(this).html().match(/myexpressionhere/);
}).after().append('<img src="myImage" />');
```

When I run the code it adds my image to each anchor link as it is supposed to. However, it adds them INSIDE the link like:

```
<a ...> yada yada <img src="myImage" /></a>
```

instead of after, like I want:

```
<a ...> yada yada</a><img src="myImage" />
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.after`, you insert the element you want to append inside the brackets:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html().match(/myexpressionhere/);
}).after('<img src="myImage" />');
```